# Giving incorrect(non-existing) queue name while publishing in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using AyncRabbitTemplate for publishing messages. Giving an incorrect(non-existing) queue name while publishing - it drops the message silently.

I have tried enabling "confirm" and "mandate" on the AyncRabbitTemplate and added the required callback methods as below:

```
@Bean
AsyncRabbitTemplate template() {
    RabbitTemplate rabbit = rabbitTemplate();
    rabbit.setChannelTransacted(true);         //to throw error when channel shuts down in case of incorrect exchange names

    AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncRabbitTemplate = new AsyncRabbitTemplate(rabbit, rpcReplyMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory()));
    asyncRabbitTemplate.setEnableConfirms(true);
    asyncRabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);         //if the message cannot be delivered to a queue an AmqpMessageReturnedException will be thrown
    return asyncRabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer rpcReplyMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueueNames(Constants.REPLY_QUEUE);
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

And the callback methods as:

```
RabbitConverterFuture<String> future = this.asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("",Constants.SNS_QUEUE, "This is the request message ",new MessagePostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) {
            message.getMessageProperties().setTimestamp(new Date());
            message.getMessageProperties().setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            return message;
        }
    });


    ListenableFuture<Boolean> future2 = future.getConfirm();
    future2.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
            System.out.println("Publish Result " + result);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println("Publish Failed: " + ex);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#template-confirms) you have to enable returned messages on the connection factory.

The send will not throw an exception but undeliverable messages will be returned to the `ReturnCallback` (if mandatory is true).

Confirms are not sent for undeliverable messages. A negative confirmation is only received if there is some kind of problem in the broker; they are rare.

Comment: Consider to call `future.get()`. We have a test-case for the `setMandatory(true)`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/AsyncRabbitTemplateTests.java#L231-L244